# How to make Sider selected key be responsive?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, antd

What I'm trying to do is get which is the key of the sider the user is using (without ReactDOM and with functional components)

my sample code here:

```
  export default function DrawerSider() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [selectedKey, setSelectedKey] = useState("sub1")

  const handleSelectKey = function(key, history_string) {
    setSelectedKey(key)
    history.push(history_string)
    console.log(key)
  }

  return (
    <Sider width={200} className="site-layout-background">
      <Menu 
        defaultSelectedKeys={selectedKey}    
        mode="inline"
        style={{ height: "100%", borderRight: 0 }}
      >
        <Menu.Item
          key="sub1"
          icon={<HomeOutlined />}
          onClick={() => handleSelectKey("sub1","/dashboard/resumo")}
        >
          Dashboard
        </Menu.Item>
        <SubMenu key="sub2" icon={<UserOutlined />} title="Usuários">
          <Menu.Item
            key="1"
            icon={<PlusCircleOutlined />}
            onClick={() => handleSelectKey("1","/usuarios/novo")}
          >
            Adicionar usúario
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item
            key="2"
            icon={<TableOutlined />}
            onClick={() => handleSelectKey("2","/usuarios/todos")}
          >
            Todos usúarios
          </Menu.Item>
        </SubMenu>
        <SubMenu key="sub3" icon={<FormOutlined />} title="Formulários">
          <Menu.Item
            key="3"
            icon={<PlusCircleOutlined />}
            onClick={() => handleSelectKey("3","/formularios/novo")}
          >
            Adicionar formulário
          </Menu.Item>            
          </SubMenu>
        </SubMenu>
      </Menu>
    </Sider>
  );
}
```

Obs: `I'm using ant design lib`

Someone knows how to make it works?

I tried to use a const on click event  to set a state of the selected key , but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `onClick` on `Menu.Item`

only `Menu` component has onClick or onSelect, both will give you callback of the "clicked" key, the differences is onClick is for any menu item click (including expanding menu) while on select is when you select an actual menu item.

There are 2 ways to get the history string:

1 - use the history string as menuItem key:
the issue would be you cannot have 2 menu item that has same history key

2 - have a map which maps the menu key to history string

see below demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/inline-menu-antd-4-18-2-forked-bgwyj?file=/index.js

```
      const handleOnSelect = ({ item, key, keyPath, selectedKeys, domEvent }) => {
        console.log(item);
        console.log(keyPath);
        console.log(selectedKeys);
        console.log(domEvent);
        handleSelectKey(key);
      };

...
..
<Menu
  onSelect={handleOnSelect}
...
>
...
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the selected key as part of the component's state. You can set the current selected key as part of the onClick.

```
const selectedKey, setSelectedKey = useState("defaultSelectedKey")
```

Not sure what the useHistory hook is for but if you need to set that onClick as well as the selectedKey, move it all into one function like so

```
const handleSelectKey = function(key, history_string) {
  setSelectedKey(key)
  history.push(history_string)
}

...

onclick={() => handleSelectedKey("3", "/usuarios/novo")}
```

https://ant.design/components/menu/

**EDIT**

Based on research into your design library, your onclick and handle select must be at the top level of the menu component. Just copy the syntax that they use in their example code.

https://ant.design/components/menu/

Comment: I did the way that you said (take a look at my new edit), but it also not worked , you know why ?

Comment: when I do a console.log in the const handleselectkey and in the key it says me diferent numbers most of the cases the selectedkey always print the initial state but the but shows the correct key you know why ?

Comment: It's hard to know what you are dong, you don't even really outline what your actual problem is and what isn't working. I am just trying to explain that you need to store the selected key in the component's state so that you can retrieve it later. I think you should read up more on react states and hooks to understand more in depth.

Comment: I'm not receiving any error , the only problem is that the selected key is not matching with my actual key.

Comment: What actual key? The one you click on for the menu vs what gets printed in the console? When you do a console log immediately after updating the state it will not always display the update because react is asynchronous.

Comment: The key is the prop key at the menu item , and I did a promise to get the actual state and it never changes it always get the initial state .

Comment: I have updated the answer, you must read the documentation and code thoroughly, I have pointed you in the right direction with using the state for your key, now you must do it in the way your design library does it.